# Mono-oxidized and dioxidized tryptophan

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, proteins

I'm translating a Russian text in which there is the following diagram of tryptophan degradation:

> [image]

Further on in the text, hydroxytryptophan is called "the **mono-oxidized form**" (моноокисленная форма) and dihydroxytryptophan is called "the **dioxidized form**" (диокисленная форма). Is this correct and would this be understood by the readers if I translate it as-is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can use [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) to check out how often and in which context proposed words and their combination is used/has been used in the literature.

Second, I feel that "*mono-oxidized*" is overly redundant and just "*oxidized*" will deliver. Even in Russian you would rarely say so ("*моноокисленный*" or "*единожды окисленный*" is usually seen as an unnecessary complication in most cases). For "*dioxidized*" there are [plenty examples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dioxidized&year_start=1900&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdioxidized%3B%2Cc0) when it is used in a similar context both in inorganic and bio chemistry, so it should a safe usage from what I see.

There is also an another option to say "*two-stage oxidation*" ("*окисленный по двум ступеням*") instead of "*dioxidized*" if you want to underline that the process has been carried out step by step.

Comment: Thank you! I googled for "monooxidized tryptophan". I'm not sure how Ngram could help me in this case. I was not sure whether the addition of the **-OH** group could be called "mono/di/oxidation", because I last self-studied chemistry in April.. zero free time.

Comment: I googled that too and the first link was [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/iub.1451/pdf) where "*mono-oxidized (+16) and dioxidized (+32) form of tryptophan*" expression has been used. So again, I see both mono-oxidized and dioxidized valid, though subjectively the *mono* prefix is not necessary.